# Automated User Interface Testing with Visual Studio Team Services

Tags: c#, visual-studio, testing, azure-devops, white-framework

I am working on a WPF application and wanted to try the continuous integration workflow with Visual Studio Team Services.

Is it possible to use the [*TestStack.White* library](https://www.nuget.org/packages/TestStack.White/) for my automated UI tests in the cloud with Visual Studio Team Services?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to [host your own Build Agent](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/build/admin/agents/v2-windows). The Hosted Build agents that Visual Studio Team Services uses cannot be run in **interactive mode**, which will be required for White to run and interact with your application.

From [VisualStudio.com](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/build/admin/agents/hosted-pool):

> Q: Do you need to run your build service in interactive mode (not as a
>   service)?
>
> A: No. Then you can use the hosted pool.